# Multivariable function continuity with a if $x=x_0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$x_0 = (0,0)$.
Define $$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{y-\max(2|x|,\sqrt{x^4+y^2})}{\sqrt{\max(|x|,|y|)+\sqrt{|x||y| }}}&\quad \text{if}\quad (x,y)\neq x_0 \\
 a&\quad \text{if} \quad (x,y)=x_0.
\end{cases}  $$
The question is, is it possible to find $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. the function is continuous in $x_0$.

The hint given in the exercise is to find a candidate for a first. I tried taking the limit at $(x,0)$ and $(0,x)$ and both are $0.$ Should $a$ be $0$ then? What other possibilities are there?

The assistant told me I have to prove that there's an infinity of possible sequences. But how do I show that?

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$\max\left(2|x|,\sqrt{x^4+y^2}\right)=\frac{2|x|+\sqrt{x^4+y^2}+\left|2|x|-\sqrt{x^4+y^2}\right|}2$$

$$\max\left(|x|,|y|\right)=\frac{|x|+|y|-\left||x|-|y|\right|}2$$

then

$$\dfrac{y-\max(2|x|,\sqrt{x^4+y^2})}{\sqrt{\max(|x|,|y|)+\sqrt{|x||y| }}}=\frac{y-\frac{2|x|+\sqrt{x^4+y^2}+\left|2|x|-\sqrt{x^4+y^2}\right|}2}{\sqrt{\frac{|x|+|y|-\left||x|-|y|\right|}2+\sqrt{|x||y| }}}=$$

$$=\sqrt r\,\frac{\sin \theta-\frac{2|\cos \theta|+\sqrt{r^2\cos^4 \theta+\sin^2 \theta}+\left|2|\cos \theta|-\sqrt{r^2\cos^4 \theta+\sin^2 \theta}\right|}2}{\sqrt{\frac{|\cos \theta|+|\sin \theta|-\left||\cos \theta|-|\sin \theta|\right|}2+\sqrt{|\cos \theta||\sin \theta| }}} \to 0$$

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted?

Comment: @Hal I don't know, no comment was left. Let me know what are you thoughts about this solution. Thanks

Comment: Aren't these necessary but not sufficient conditions?

Comment: @Hal I'll try with a different approach.

Comment: @Hal WHat about this other approach?

Comment: You sure have my like. Actually your answer inspired me this: since we want to prove continuity at $0$, let $(x,y)$ be in the interior of the unit disk. This facilitaties to find an upper bound, e.g. $|y - \max (2|x|,\sqrt{x^4+y^2})|\ \leq |3|$, which further simplifies the proof of its convergence to $0$.

Comment: @Hal  It could be a good idea. But what do you obtain in this way? You hould add an aswer here.